# Is it possible to eliminate the blue border when selecting cells?

Tags: react-data-grid

I am trying to remove the blue border that appears when you click a cell when using [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid). Is this possible, or will I have to create a pull request?

Comment: Are you using the default bootstrap css?

Comment: Because it tells you to use a default one on the github page.

Comment: A good example of how to modify bootstrap colors is located here: https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203

Comment: As @Daniel Sixl said in his answer, rdg-selected is the class tag for that border. You could override that class tag to have no border at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for `.rdg-selected`. React Data Grid uses an absolutely positioned extra div for the so called **cell-mask**.

```
.rdg-selected {
    border: 2px solid #66afe9;
}
```

The cell-mask looks like this:

```
<div tabindex="0">
   <div data-test="cell-mask" class="rdg-selected" style="height: 35px; width: 256px; z-index: 5; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; transform: translate(256px, 0px);"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want to get rid of the blue border, set the border of this element to none:

```
.rdg-selected {
    /* border: 2px solid #66afe9; */
    border: none;
}
```

Or give it a transparent border-color:

```
.rdg-selected {
    /* border: 2px solid #66afe9; */
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Watch out for specificity of your style.